# modifying a Wordpress header

Tags: wordpress

I hired a guy to set up a Wordpress site for me. I need to make changes but unfortunately I have run out of money and have to try to make the changes myself. I am a programmer (Python and C++) so I can pick up concepts quickly, but I am just unfamiliar with Wordpress.

The website is at http://www.brilliantzenaudio.com

The first thing I need to do is put a slogan in the header (I mean some text.) I don't quite understand where the wordpress header comes from. Currently mine shows a logo and a menu. The following code I got from the Wordpress control panel, going to Appearance -> Editor -> Roots: Header. Would I add my slogan text to this file?

```
<header class="banner" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">Brilliant Zen Audio</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-3">
        <nav role="navigation" class="clearfix">
          <?php
            if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
              wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => ''));
            endif;
          ?>
        </nav>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't quite understand where the wordpress header comes from

In the `index.php` file of your theme's root folder, following function call adds the header in the theme

```
get_header(' '); // adds/includes "header.php"
```

`Wordpress` uses `header.php` file to represent the header, so in your theme's root folder, find this (`header.php`) file and edit it.
Read more on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) about header.

Comment: This is the relevant code I see in index.php. This is at the top of index.php. What does this get_template_part() function do? `<?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>`

Comment: `get_header( $name );` accepts only one optional parameter, AFAIK. Did you read the [doc here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)?

Answer (score 0):

u can add your text right after .  It will display your text right after your sites name on the front-end, it is probebly a good idea to put it between

& <\p>. 
The generic sulotion will be to Use 'inspect elment' with your browser to find the location u want the text to apear on the page, than search that location (ex.  using a software developer env find that location (ex. Netbeans).